# Inverse of elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $Q^{p}_{q}\left( \lambda \right) = E_m + \lambda \left(0,...,e_p,...,0\right)$. How to show that $Q^{p}_{q}\left( \lambda \right)Q^{p}_{q}\left( - \lambda \right) = E_m$ holds true?

Comment: Your second sentence does not make sense as written and it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Updated the second sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that $p\neq q$.  Otherwise, the statement no longer holds.

Note that we can write $Q^p_q(\lambda) = E_m + \lambda e_pe_q^T$.  With that, we find
$$
Q^p_q(\lambda) Q^p_q(-\lambda)= 
(E_m + \lambda e_pe_q^T)(E_m - \lambda e_pe_q^T) 
\\ =E_m + \lambda e_pe_q^T - \lambda e_p e_q^T + \lambda^2 (e_pe_q^T)(e_pe_q^T)
\\= E_m + \lambda^2 (e_pe_q^T)(e_pe_q^T)\\
= E_m  + \lambda^2 e_p(e_q^Te_p)e_q^T\\
= E_m + \lambda^2 e_p(0) e_q^T
\\ = E_m
$$
as was desired.

Comment: Why is $\left( e_q^Te_p \right) = 0$?

Comment: Try it for $m = 3$ and I think it will be clear that this is the case

Comment: How would $e_q$ and $e_p$ look like for $m = 3$? $e_q = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @philk982 that is true when $q = 2$.  So for instance, if $p = 1$ and $q = 2$ we have
$$
e_p = e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, \quad e_q = e_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0}.
$$